# ngx-file-drop - `openFileSelector()` does not seem to produce a usable File object

Tags: angular, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to get file uploads to work using the [ngx-file-drop module](https://github.com/georgipeltekov/ngx-file-drop#readme).

This is what I have so far:

```
<ngx-file-drop (onFileDrop)="dropped($event)" [showBrowseBtn]="true">
    <ng-template ngx-file-drop-content-tmp let-openFileSelector="openFileSelector">
        <div (click)="openFileSelector()" class="file-drop-content">
            <h2>Drag File Here</h2>
            <span>or click to browse</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-file-drop>
```

It currently works fine for files that are dragged/dropped, but not for "click to browse" files.  It'll allow me to browse for & select a file, but the `FileEntry` object that it sends back is missing the `filesystem` & `fullPath` properties:

[image: added via click-to-browse]

which are present in the drag/drop version:

[image: drag/drop version]

making the click-to-browse version unusable (afaict).

I imagine I'm missing some config somewhere.  I'm not super familiar with this module, as I'm just taking over the project from someone else.

**Anyone have any ideas what would cause the drag/drop file to be different from the click-to-browse file?**

Answer (score 0):

I found that the lack of `filesystem`/`filePath` properties doesn't matter.

What *does* matter is that, in the "click to browse" scenario, `ctx-file-drop.js` creates a "fake" `FileEntry` object where the `file()` method simply calls a callback.  So it fires *immediately*.  Whereas, in the drag/drop case, a regular FileEntry object is created.  The `file()` method, there, does NOT fire immediately.

In my case, this was causing problems because, further down the processing chain, I had:

```
public readFile(fileEntry: FileSystemFileEntry): Observable<File> {

    const subject: Subject<File> = new Subject<File>();

    fileEntry.file((f: File) => {
        subject.next(f);
        subject.complete();
    });

    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

The fake `FileEntry.file()` was firing before anything could subscribe to the `Observable`.  I resolved it by changing the `Subject` to a `new ReplaySubject(1)`.